# Express $y=|-x^2+1|$ as a piecewise function.

Tags: functions, absolute-value

I'm unsure of how to start this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: How is the absolute value function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for real $z,$$$ |z|=\begin{cases} z &\mbox{if } z\ge0 \\
-z & \mbox{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

$$|-x^2+1|=\begin{cases} -x^2+1 &\mbox{if } -x^2+1\ge0 \iff -1\le x\le 1 \\
-(-x^2+1)=x^2-1 & \mbox{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

Comment: Why provide the whole answer for such a simple problem?  Clearly the OP needs to think about these things for a while before getting them.

Comment: @JavaMan, simplicity is pretty relative, also the question is not marked 'Homework'

Comment: So you think the student will learn _more_ by being told the answer?  Regardless of not being marked as homework, it is clear that the best pedagogical practice would be to guide the student through the problem.

Comment: @JavaMan, It's not bad to have a look at solved problems solved in a  standard way . Also,  you will find complete answer of even simpler problems here. where you think I could leave, btw?

Comment: It's not helpful or responsible in most cases, either.  You could easily have defined the absolute value, and then asked the OP where the function $-x^2 + 1$ was greater than or equal to zero, and less than or equal to zero.  Since our conversation has turned towards pedagogy, we should stop our discussion here.

Comment: @JavaMan: As much as I agree with you, this is not, I think, the goal of math.SE. "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about math." This isn't a support forum; this is a list of Q/A meant to serve as reference for future readers. Hence why, for example, you're offered to answer your own questions while you're asking it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of any function $y = |f(x)|$ can be defined piecewise without the use of the absolute value sign:

$$y = \left|f(x)\right| = \begin{cases} f(x) & f(x) \geq 0 \\ \\ -f(x)& f(x) < 0\\ \end{cases}$$

In your case, $y = |f(x)|$ where $f(x) = -x^2 + 1$.

So you need to determine how to express, in terms of $x$, the values satisfying $f(x) \geq 0$ and $-f(x)\lt 0$.